# Maven Test classes dependencies

Tags: testing, maven, build, dependencies

I have two projects:

1) ProjectCORE

2) ProjectMAIN

For some reason, the test classes in ProjectMAIN depend on test classes in ProjectCORE, which don't get included in the ProjectCORE jar I have listed as a dependency for ProjectMAIN, causing compile problems in ProjectMAIN.

How to work this out, preferably without including the test classes in my ProjectCORE jar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possibly a candidate for using `attached tests`.  Refer to [this guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) for doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it out and post back with results.